# Min/Max combobox dynamic functionality

Tags: java

Developing a Java SWT application.

2 comboboxes. One **min**, one **max** , when referring to number of bedrooms for a house.

**Min** has entries, in order : (No min, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

**Max** has entries, in order : (No max, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

If a user changes **min** to show 3 bedrooms,  the **max** combobox should update to show (No max, 3, 4, 5, 6) without changing what is selected in **max**.

TLDR: Replicate Redfin's(redfin.com) min/max functionality for bedrooms.

This might sound very easy, but I've been stuck on removing/adding entries without triggering some out of bounds exception and having the lists change.

Are there "twin" "min/max" combo box libraries? I can't find anything like what I'm describing. If not, what is a clear, elegant solution to this problem?

so far I'm focusing on one combobox at a time, but it might be generalized?:

```
void UpdateMaxBeds(int index, String text) //index and text of what was selected in min
    {

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 6;i++)
        {
            Integer curr = Integer.getInteger(max_beds.getItem(i));
            if(curr<index)
            {
                max_beds.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `i--` when you remove and using `< max_list.size()` instead of the hard coded `<= 6` like so:

```java
void UpdateMaxBeds(int index, String text) //index and text of what was selected in min
{
    for (int i = 1; i < max_beds.size(); i++)
    {
        Integer curr = Integer.getInteger(max_beds.getItem(i));
        if(curr<index)
        {
            max_beds.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

`i--` keeps you from skipping the element following the removed one on the next for loop iteration. The `max_list.size()` keeps you from trying to access and remove out of bounds elements since removing changes the size of the list(assuming list).

**Problems not addressed in this but should not be ignored:**

- The code does not handle adding elements back if the min is relaxed in a later selection. (You could reset the max list before every call to the default.)
- If the selected max is one of the elements removed. (You could set it to the new min value or just default to no max.)